# How to disable PS3 accelerometers through usb, no bluetooth

Tags: 14.04, drivers, usb, emulation, ps3

how do I disable the tilt accelerometers when using ps3 controller with usb? I dont have a bluetooth adapter and i dont wanna buy one.

i am using 64 bit ubuntu 14.04 with patched kernel 3.13.11.6+

qtsixa settings does not modify my controller in any way no matter what settings i use. i think thats because its not connected through bluetooth. however it does see the controller and i can use the controller, but the tilt accelerometers get in the way when trying to setup controls for emulators.

i have googled and googled, but all i find are how to's involving bluetooth.

please help me solve this issue -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a workaround that effectively disables them using jstest-gtk, i increased the deadzone in the calibration menu for the corresponding axis's that the tilt accelerometers use, and now they don't do anything unless im shaking my controller. i can now set controls without them in the way.

i set all the values on the axis's 23-26 to:

```
248, 574, 63, 959
```

not much of a change from the original values but this works for me.